# Java - MouseListener in another class?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouselistener

I realize this is a repeat question, but my circumstances are a little bit different. I need to have a MouseListener in another class that can altar the background color of the object that calls it. Please help me.

```
public class LeftListPanel extends JPanel {

public LeftListPanel() {
    setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    setLayout(null);

    addPersonalStatsTab();
}

private void addPersonalStatsTab() {
    JPanel personalStatsPanel = new JPanel();
    personalStatsPanel.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseListener());

    JLabel personalStatsText = new JLabel("Text");
    personalStatsPanel.add(personalStatsText);

    add(personalStatsPanel);
}
```

Then I have an inner-nested class for the MouseListener because this is the only place this MouseListener will be called.

```
class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR.brighter());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    }

}
```

The setBackground(COLOR) lines are those who don't work... this.setBack and super.setBack ARE NOT working in this case.. I'M DESPERATE FOR HELP!

Comment: Sooo, either pass a reference of the object you want to a call to the `MouseListener` OR extract the object form the `source` property of the event object - you will need to use `instanceof` to test that you are getting the expected type of object and then cast it - which will probably be the two most common answers to all related questions

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work".  Does your program compile and run?  Does anything happen when the mouse enters and exits the personal stats tab?  Is there any kind of error message or stack trace?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I pass a reference into that class? I tried the only way I know how, which is adding a constructor in the MouseListener class.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem By "doesn't work" I mean the code setBackground has no object to reference.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking about the effect of that.  Does your code compile?  Does it run?  Does anything change colour when your mouse enters the personal stats tab?

Comment: @LoyalDakota That's basic programming 101 - Maybe you should start with [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the background changes is that when you call `setBackground`, you are de-referring (implicitly) the `this` object, i.e. the instance of `LeftListPanel`. So, you *are actually* changing its background, but you don't see it because inside the LeftListPanel instance there is another JPanel (instantiated at the `addPersonalStatsTab` method) which occupies the whole visible space (or even it is not visible at all, because of that weird `null` layout; I don't know exactly).

- Fist of all, I recommend to you not to set `null` as a layout. Chose a proper layout, or let it be defaulted - do not call `setLayout(null)`.
- Then, set `personalStatsPanel` as a *private member* of `LeftListPanel`. And when calling to `setBackground`, use it as the scope reference:

  ```
      LeftListPanel.this.personalStatsPanel.setBackground(...);
  ```

Comment: the null layout is a layout that allows you to explicitly set the bounds of the object within the frame. For a smaller project like this one, I used a mixture of null, gridbag, and border.

Sadly, what you told me to try did not work. LeftListPanel.this.--- can not find the personalStatsPanel object, whether its private or public.

Comment: I understood `CustomMouseListener` is an inner class within `LeftListPanel`, in which case it should see any private members of LeftListPanel. If it is not, you should add a constructor to `CustomMouseListener` which receive a reference of `personalStatsPanel` and store it privately.

Answer (score 0):

This works, I instead just created a private method where I pass in the panel I want to apply it too.

```
private void CustomMouseListener(JPanel panel) {
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR.brighter());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        }

    });
}
```

Thank you all for your time and suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

## You could...

Pass a reference of the component you want changed to the `CustomMouseListener`

```
class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    private JPanel panel;

    public CustomMouseListener(JPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR.brighter());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    }

}
```

This is okay if you want to use the listener on a limited number of components, but if you want to use the same listener on a number of components...

## You could...

Use the `source` property of the `MouseEvent` to get which component triggered the event

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (!(e.getSource() instanceof JPanel)) {
        return;
    }
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)e.getSource();
    panel.setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR.brighter());
}
```

or, a better solution would be to do something more like...

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    e.getComponent().setBackground(Settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR.brighter());
}
```

since the information is already provided to you (just not, this returns an instance of `Component`, so if you need to access the Swing specific properties, you'd still need to cast it).

Why is this approach better?

```
CustomMouseListener listener = new CustomMouseListener();
panel1.addMouseListener(listener);
panel2.addMouseListener(listener);
panel3.addMouseListener(listener);
panel4.addMouseListener(listener);
panel5.addMouseListener(listener);
panel6.addMouseListener(listener);
panel7.addMouseListener(listener);
```

because it's agnostic, meaning you can create a single instance of the listener and re-use on multiple components